# Сумма по отдельным полям таблицы

Tags: sql

Всем добрый день. 
Имеется такая таблица - [image: скрин таблицы]
Задача - достать сумму очков по каждому пилоту из этой таблицы. 
То есть на данный момент нужно получить в результате что-то вроде такой таблицы:

```
id_driver sum(points)
1                50
2                33
```

Возможно ли это сделать одним запросом? 
Понятно, что можно сначала достать уникальный список всех пилотов
 `SELECT DISTINCT id_driver from results`, а потом по каждому айдишнику сделать запрос `SELECT SUM (points) FROM results WHERE id_driver=1` итд. Но это будет много запросов получается.

Можно ли как-то одним запросом сразу вытащить инфу по всем пилотам, подсчитав у них у каждого отдельно сумму? Че-то фантазии и познаний не хватает. Спасибо.

Comment: про `GROUP BY` не слышал или не осилил?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `group by`

```
SELECT id_driver,  
       SUM (points) 
from   results 
group  by id_driver
```